# Need help on showing the test output in html format containing screen capture link

Tags: webdriver

I have a framework with Webdriver+testng.
I want the result of all the methods i have run, in html format with their status and screen capture link.

please let me know whts the way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [this](http://www.thucydides.info/), But this only for BDD styled stories. If you are looking for a plain web driver scripts, [try this selenium loggers](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

TestNG creates a report in HTML format in 'test-output' folder (or, if you're using testNG plugin in Eclipse, you can specify the path in Window-Preferences-testNG). The folder is created and rewritten after each run. Look for index.html there.

You can add custom information there using Reporter.log (from org.testng.Reporter), the information can be found after 'Reporter output' link in the report. So basically all you need is an @AfterMethod which will take the screenshot and embed it into the log. [This discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/aG86La7Nh6A/P6rY1k9cIcAJ) may help.